# For Loop Does Not Work

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uialertview

I am trying to make a guessing app for school.

```
-(IBAction)check:(id)sender
{
    if (answerField.text.length > 0)
    {
        [self number];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:@"Please type in more than one chracter"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [error show];
    }
}
-(void)number
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (answerField.text > strNumber)
        {

            hlLabel.text = @"Guess Lower";
            answerField.text = @"";
        }
        if (answerField.text < strNumber)
        {

            hlLabel.text = @"Guess Higher";
            answerField.text = @"";
        }
    }


}
```

**The Problem:** The for loop does not work. It only checks once. Also, everytime it checks, it always says "Guess Higher" when in fact, I guess higher than the computer generate number.

**Other Information:** I have a method where every time I click the keyboard done from the textfield, it will check the number method.

Comment: Where is strNumber coming from?

Comment: shouldn't you ask user for input in each cycle of the loop?

Comment: Also, why would you want to loop this? What is the point? I mean, you have an action for check, so there is no need to loop it. Simply have an if/then statement. That is all, now your only problem is it detecting incorrectly. Of course, it is almost certainly your error. You just need to locate it. So, code you please show how you have setup strNumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`answerField.text` is returning an `NSString`, not a number.

Try `answerField.text.intValue`.

And `strNumber` must be an integer for that to work, btw.

Comment: So before, the loop would have been comparing an address to an int... brilliant.

Comment: Yep, that would do it. Good job bbum!

Comment: For the OP's information, answerField.text gives you an NSString. NSStrings in Objective-C are simply pointers to a string value in memory. Because of this, even if the string value is say 1, you really are comparing: Is X greater than "10x78570268" or something. You must use intValue as bbum said. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to understand what you were trying to do. But I suspect that you are just trying to have a user enter some number in a field to guess a number with up to 100 attempts. Something like that.

But a for loop is not how you can make a *user* retry something. What you need is some state saved in the object (i.e. an ivar) which counts each attempt.

Second problem here is that it seems you are numerically comparing strings which does not make sense here. You want to compare numerical *values*.

So your program would likely look like:

```
-(IBAction)check:(id)sender
{
    if (answerField.text.length > 0)
    {
        [self checkFieldValueAgainstCorrectAnswer]; // use better naming
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:@"Please type in more than one chracter"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [error show];
    }
}

-(void)checkFieldValueAgainstCorrectAnswer
{
    NSUInteger fieldValue = [answerField.text unsignedIntegerValue];
    NSUInteger correctValue = [strNumber unsignedIntegerValue];
    if (fieldValue > correctValue) {
        // guess lower
    } else if(fieldValue < correctValue) {
        // guess higher
    } else {
        // you won!
        return;
    }
    answerField.text = @"";
    attempts++;
    if (attempts > 100) {
        // Too many attemps, you lost!
    }
 }
```